# DrawerLayout with nested ViewPager - swiping in ViewPager

Tags: android, nested, android-viewpager, drawerlayout

I have a `ViewPager` in my `DrawerLayout` and I want it to handle the swipe gestures, but the parent `DrawerLayout` does handle them and so the `ViewPager` does not work if the swipe direction matches the `DrawerLayout`'s close direction...

I tried arround with `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` on the `DrawerLayout` but this seems to have no effect at all...

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: Have you found any solution?